# Is there any message prioritizing in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, priority-queue

When I do some asynchronous call in javascript, I put callback function into some queue, right?

May I control the queue position where function is put somehow? Explicitly or by some priority?

**UPDATE 1**

My question is not only about AJAX. There are several places where asynchronous calls used in JS (I may be wrong):

1. event handlers
2. XMLHttpRequest calls
3. setTimeout()/setInterval()

According to replies, I consider the general answer is NO, i.e. message queue is not accessible from javascript.

Comment: Where does JavaScript allow to put callback functions of asynchronous requests into a queue?

Comment: @Gumbo: Why are you repeating the question?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I interpret the question in a way that Dims assumes that there already is a queue for request callbacks and he just don’t know how to prioritize its elements.

Comment: @Gumbo: An answer to his first sub-question "[..], right?" will take care of that.

Comment: Gumbo, see my Update 1 about my opinion about where async calls are in JS

Answer (score 3):

No.  The browser doesn't maintain an actual queue of asynchronous requests.  Not all browsers necessarily handle it the same way, but conceptually the browser simply suspends the thread that is handling the request until the response to that request returns or the timer expires.  At that point, it resumes executing the thread in the callback with the data supplied by the response.  I'm sure that I've oversimplified it, but with any more detail the answer would probably differ depending on which browser we're talking about.

If you want an ordering for your AJAX requests, you'll need to build the mechanism or find an existing JavaScript plugin/library to do that.  The simplest way is probably just to make subsequent requests in the callbacks of requests that should take precedence.  That way you know that they will occur later than the ones that should go before them.  Timers, of course, invoke their callbacks when they expire.  You could order them, if desired, by being careful with the expiration times.

Comment: There's no need to build your own implementation, just use one that's readily available (and well tested). E.g., a jQuery plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/AjaxQueue) or a standalone javascript engine (http://www.cmarshall.net/MySoftware/ajax/index.html).

Comment: @lsoliveira yes, by "build" I simply meant using code written in javascript rather than a browser implementation.  Using an existing plugin is probably the best way, especially if you're already using the framework the plugin works with.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to let the OP know that there are alternatives. Either way, reading the question again, I'm not even sure if it refers to AJAX calls (as opposed to a callback executing as part of a timer being triggered with setTimeout/setInterval).

Comment: What if several events occur simultaneously? For example, user press button and ajax response come? Or user move mouse at the same instant timeout elapse? If it would no queue, one of this events would be lost. So, I completely disagree that browser have no queues but I understood that they are not accessible.

Comment: @Dims I didn't say that the browser didn't maintain a data structure of pending requests, it's just not a queue (FIFO) which implies some ordering to how they are processed.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is include a sequence number in every request (and response) and use the same callback handler for every AJAX call. This way your callback handler can check the sequence number returned and manage the order of execution of callbacks.

i.e. something like:

every AJAX request will be like `/getUsers?seq=1&...`, `/getProps?seq=2&...` etc..

every AJAX response (assuming JSON here) will return the seq num is received with the request, i.e.

```
result {
  seq: 2,
  data: ...
}
```

then your callback handler will look something like:

```
var responseQ = [];
function handler(response) {
  // .. code to push the response into the responseQ in increasing order of seq num ..
}
```

and you can have a queue processor execute every N seconds, which checks for outstanding responses in the Q and processes them accordingly..

i.e. something like:

```
setInterval(function() {

  // get last item from responseQ
  // check its seq num  
  // execute if appropriate

}, 10000);
```

Comment: this will not work (or, at least, would have to be seriously expanded) if the reason for the OP to want to queue the requests is serializing server access (richfaces does this, for instance).

Comment: Yes, this will have to be expanded quite a bit. I was only pointing out a highlevel strategy outline for developing an AJAX queuing strategy.